# code igniter admin folder not working in localhost wamp server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Code igniter admin module creation issue in `wamp` server.

This one is working for me in local file and the server path
localhost/site/

but the admin folder is not working in `wamp` server, the server uploaded files are working and am getting the admin folder. 
localhost/site/admin/

This was downloaded from the server for testing purpose, why it is not working in localhost admin folder. Please guide me, how will get rid of this issue.

Comment: Please define what is "not working" for you.  Is it a 404 error?  Is it a 500 error?  Is it a blank page?  It could be a lot of things...

Answer (score -1):

wampp issue with mode revrite  use apache 
for those of you who think wampp is a creaton for got to help you make the word better bad news

if you chek google wampp mod_rewrite not working About 254,000 results 
and if the url was working on a normal server and not on a local host it has noting to do with codeigniter it has much to do with winshit and xampp.

youse it widout mode rewrite and .htaccess

```
url/index.php/someign
```

Comment: 1) OP is using WAMP 2) xampp uses apache 3) what issue, please be somewhat more thorough in your answer, as it is now it doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa xampp is using a cut off apache with missing parts .. many of the normal tings are not wirking like mod_rewrite if you want to fast on the road you buy your self a fast car not a bycicle

Comment: Still though, the poster is using http://www.wampserver.com/en/, not http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa still thugh the issue is because he is using xampp wamp same ting